# Convert website JSON data to CSV python, returns JSON decode error

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert the JSON at this URL: https://wtrl.racing/assets/js/miscttt170620.php?wtrlid=63, which I have saved in a file, to a CSV using this code:

```
json_data_file = open('TTT json', 'r')
content = json.load(json_data_file)
csv_results = csv.writer(open("TTT_results.csv.csv", "w", newline=''))
for item in content:
    print(item)
    csv_results.writerow(item)
```

This returns: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 489351 (char 489350)`, which is the '2' in this section of JSON `"ll": 43.529}, {"aa":`

I'm bemused as to why this would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the json is malformed. You need to contact the person that generated this json to fix it.

See the entries:

```
"cc": "Nick "Lionel" Berry(TriTalk)"

"cc": ""Sherpa" Dave (R&amp;K Hyenas)"
```

These quotes are not properly escaped. It needs to be:

```
"cc": "Nick \"Lionel\" Berry(TriTalk)"

"cc": "\"Sherpa\" Dave (R&amp;K Hyenas)"
```

Looks like you're probably requesting the wrong accept encoding when accessing the data. Try downloading it by specifying that you want a JSON response and not an HTML payload:

```
import requests

url = 'https://wtrl.racing/assets/js/miscttt170620.php?wtrlid=63'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Ah, that's a problem, I can't really do this any ideas on how to change this, perhaps a for loop which has a replace, I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: @PythonIsBae Check the updated response! It all works if you provide the correct headers!

Comment: I was about to mention... from the browser you get an html page without proper escaping. If you select and save the allegedly json data, you get errors. But if you use python's request module or a command line tool like wget or curl, you get the json encoded stuff properly.

Comment: @flakes so if I run that code, my CSV is `d,a,t,a`, if I `print(data)` it returns `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 169648-169649: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: ^ I assume this is the reason that it doesn't correctly write to csv

Comment: @PythonIsBae Looks like a character encoding issue. `print(data)` works on my environment. What does `print(response.encoding)` say?

Comment: @flakes it says UTF-8